# Three way comparison using hash

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, string-comparison

I need a way to compare three hashes based on the hostname I've extracted. I have a function to compare two but looking to combine it to do all three in one function.

All variables have been captured and stored previously. This is just a comparison check.

I do not want to us isdiff or some other function if it can be avoided.

Need to compare three results.

results1 = {'uspn-hs-r3': ('uspn-hs-r3', 'archive\uspn-hs-r3.cfg', '23d516b3f2f438327b1a19fa63868621a87b8c8b')' etc.....

These values can very, hence the compare. The string is far to long to show it all. However the hostname in this case is uspn-hs-r3 followed by the :, then the directory it was in, followed by the hash.

results2
results3

**Two Way Comparison:**

```
for hostname, filename, filehash in results1.values():
        if hostname in results2:
            _, filename2, filehash2 = results2[hostname]
            if filehash != filehash2:
                print ("%s has a change (%s, %s)" % (
                    hostname, filehash, filehash2))
                print(filename)
                print(filename2)
```

**Failed 3 way:**

```
for hostname, filename, filehash in results1.values():
    if hostname in results2 and hostname in results3:
        _, filename2, filehash2, filename3, filehash3 = results3[hostname]
        if filehash != filehash2 or filehash != filehash3:
            print ("%s has a change (%s, %s)" % (
                    hostname, filehash, filehash2, filehash3))
            print(filename)
            print(filename2)
            print(filename3)
```

Comment: Please show examples of `results1/2/3` so that we can understand their structure and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in line 3. ***result3*** only has a tuple of size 3 and you're unpacking it to 5 values.

```
for hostname, filename, filehash in results1.values():
    if hostname in results2 and hostname in results3:
        _, filename2, filehash2 = results2[hostname]
        _, filename3, filehash3 = results3[hostname]
        if filehash != filehash2 or filehash != filehash3:
            print ("%s has a change (%s, %s, %s)" % (
                hostname, filehash, filehash2, filehash3))
            print(filename)
            print(filename2)
            print(filename3)
```

Comment: I think that did it. I will run some tests to confirm but initially looks good.